# Python Pandas read_sql - call previously specified date

Tags: python, pandas

I have a sql query and I want to specify the date outside of the where query so it can be changed as needed. The following code isn't working and I'm not sure what else to try.

```
startdate='2018-01-01'

test=pd.read_sql("""select * from database.table where date > :startdate ; """ , connection)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this

```
test=pd.read_sql('select * from database.table where date > {}'.format(startdate) , connection)
```

Comment: How would this change if I wanted date between startdate and enddate?   where date between {} and {}""".format(startdate, enddate)     doesn't work

Comment: It would probably look like this. `'select * from database.table where date > {} and date < {}'.format(startdate, enddate)`